# Using flash images with after effects

Tags: flash, after-effects

I have been using flash to trace an image of a lighthouse. I used it because I found it difficult to trace the lighthouse in photoshop.

I was just wondering is it hard to take the image from flash and use it in an after effects composition?

Answer (score 0):

You can import a .swf right into AE.  What versions are you using?  Have you tried importing yet?